# Difference in usage of graphql-java vs graphql-java-tools

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java-tools

Im new to graphql found 2 java implementation 
using  from official graphql: https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v10/

and

https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools

Like whats their difference in implementing graphql in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**In Short:**

***graphql-java:***

- Is an implementation of graphQL in java based on the Javascript reference implementation [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js).  This project use to host a suit of graphql related tools for the java ecosystem including `graphql-java-tools`.  See at the end of this answer for more

***graphql-java-tools:***

- Is a Java GraphQL helper library that aids development of GraphQL schema language for your
  graphql-java API. One example is auto-configuration of classes for creating a GraphQLSchema.  See more from official documentation [here](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools#why-graphql-java-tools).  Similarly another useful library I will recommend is [spring-graphql-common](https://github.com/oembedler/spring-graphql-common#usage)

See this example [Spring Boot Project](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot) that puts it all together:

- GraphQL - Java Implementation
- GraphiQL - Workbench Gui with auto-complete assists based on your schema
- Graphql java tools - Library
- Spring Graphql Common - Library

Furthermore `graphql-Java` is currently only focussed on Java not the tooling projects.  These have been moved to their dedicated organisations.

- [graphql-spring-boot](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot)
- [graphql-java-tools](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools)
- [graphql-java-servlet](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-servlet)
- [graphql-java-annotations](https://github.com/Enigmatis/graphql-java-annotations)
- [graphql-java-type-generator](https://github.com/graphql-java/graphql-java-type-generator/)

More from the [original maintainer's blog](https://www.graphql-java.com/blog/moving-projects/)

Comment: what do you call "Spring Graphql Common"? I can't see any such thing in the repo you pointed at...

Comment: OK found in *this* example: https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/tree/master/example-spring-common